# Set autotcomplete textbox text programmatically with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material for creating a form. For some fields the user should get a autocomplete function. Those fields should be also populated from the backend, if the user provides a serial number.

My question is, how can I set the text of a textbox which is linked to a autocomplete via code?

I copied a StackBlitz and modified it to match my scenario:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-async1-jxrahv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

If you click on the "click me!" Button, I want the text of the textbox to change to "Windstorm" (which doesn't happen).

Thanks!

Comment: well your actual form control value is an object and you are trying to set the value with a string, so it won't work. If you enter it as an object, it will work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-async1-8nneha?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AJT_82 is right. Once you added `[matAutocomplete]="auto"` to input MatAutocompleteTrigger  value accessor starts handling all forms events. And MatAutocompleteTrigger uses displayWith method to write in input value. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/57aadc2588c3a745278c368d22c6d5a4471c3a3b/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L521

Comment: Being agains the rules and totally off-topic: Very nice to see you again @yurzui Long time no see. All good I hope! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes, all goes well, thanks. Have you decided to remember the angular forms?)

Comment: @yurzui Haha :D Yeah! My newest passion is ionic though. Work has gotten me into learning and developing with ionic, and I love it! :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks man! This was really great! Could you please post an answer to this question so I can mark it as answer and you earn some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding your autocomplete with array of objects, so when you are trying to set the value with "just" a string:

```ts
this.usersForm.get('userInput').setValue("Windstorm");
```

... it will not work. Set the whole object as value, and you're good! :)

```ts
this.usersForm.get('userInput').setValue({ id: 1, name: 'Windstorm' });
```

Modified **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-async1-8nneha?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Haha :D Yeah, was good! BTW, glad we got your problem sorted out, have a good end of the weekend and happy coding! :)